# Can not unlock my MacBook Pro once I locked it with Find my iPhone

Tags: macbook-pro, unlock, find-my-mac

I thought that i lost my MacBook Pro so I used Find my iPhone to lock it.
Now that I found it an interrogation point is appearing on my screen 
but there is nowhere I can write my pin. Can you please help me

Comment: Please attach an image of your screen!

Answer (score 1):

You can always power off the Mac and you will be prompted for the pin when the machine reboots.

Comment: Thank you but I found the solution . I needed to force shut down the mac then I pressed and holded the command + R buttons and then press and hold the power button after a padlock appeared and I wrote my pin and then I had to write another time my pin and my computer worked.